# Image display error in MVC6 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm getting an error in my console when rendering an image (this HTML is in a partial view within the Layout page):

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-image dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
        <img src="~/assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg" alt="Avatar">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
```

The error in the console:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). 
>   GET - `https://localhost:44356/Home/assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg`

I'm sure the error is coming from an improper path definition in the src attribute (given that Home is appearing in the path), but I've tried all the ways I know but the error continues.

I've tried

```
src="~/assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg"
src="../assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg"
src="assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg"
```

neither of those remove the error, I still get Home in the path.

**Note:** Upon further testing, the url works and gets the avatar on the Home/Index page, but fails on every other page even though this html is in the layout, not on the individual page's html.

Here is the rendered html, it is the same when it works and when it errors

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-image dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
    <img src="assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg" alt="Avatar">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. My output looks the same as yours but routing is working properly. It should be routing you back to the root of your side `http://localhost/assets`. I think something else is going on here. Is there by chance a `<base>` declared on your page? This would override the browsers default path interpretation. Another possible cause could be how you configured your routs at startup.